# Do Facebook fan pages with a fan gate get indexed by Google?

Tags: facebook, seo, facebook-apps, facebook-page, googlebot

I'm working on a Facebook fan page app (a page tab) with a 'like' fan gate (users that like the page see the real content, and users that don't see only a "like us" image).
The thing is I need the fan page to be found on Google's search.
Should the fact that only fans can enter the app in any way affect the Google bots?
I am currently assuming that it does, but I want to be sure.
And if it does it mean that I have no control over the fan page's SEO?
I have read about SEO, but I haven't found anything about this.
I would be very happy if someone here could help me, even refer me to some documentation or anything about it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your presumption is correct. Here are two workarounds:

1. Detect Google's User-Agent and display the un-gated content when
   appropriate.
2. Gate the page with a div overlay so that all the ungated content is
   still there, but simply unavailable to the user until she clicks *Like*.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick reply. I did consider the use of javascript instead of php for the fan gate at the beginning, and just hiding and showing the content, but then it means all the content will be still available, and i preferred it not to be. And about your first offer (which sounds pretty good), how can I detect google's user-agents? And couldn't i get a google penalty or something like that (I heard about something like that somewhere)? Thanks again!

Comment: Most languages have a way to detect the user agent. Here's a list of user agents: http://www.user-agents.org/ ... I think you only get a penalty for tricking the search engine with content which is obviously different (for example, feeding the search engine recipes, but serving up poems)

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll check a bit more about the penalty issue, just to be 100% sure. Thanks!